# poner color de fondo no solido en tkinter python(no desaparecerlo)

Tags: python, tkinter, python-3.8

estaba intentando que tkinter ponga los labe del color transparente y esto es lo que conseguí hasta ahora

```
    #!/usr/bin/env python
    # -*- coding: utf-8 -*-
    import os
    import pymysql
    from tkinter import*
    from tkinter import messagebox
    import tkinter
    from datetime import date
    from datetime import datetime
    from tkinter import ttk
    import tkinter.font as tkFont
    import tempfile
    import win32api
    import win32print
    
    ventana=Tk()
    ventana.wm_attributes('-transparentcolor','yellow')
    Label(ventana, text="Bienvenido a Fantoche.C.A", fg="yellow", bg="red").place(x=120,y=10)
    Algerian=tkFont.Font(family='Bodoni MT Black', size=16, weight='bold')
    dale=0
    ventana.title("Los Pioneros.C.A")
    ventana.resizable(0,0)
    #ventana .iconbitmap()
    ventana.geometry("400x300")
    "ventana=Frame()"
    "ventana.pack()"
    ventana.config(bg="#5fcde4", width="400", height="280")
    bg_image = PhotoImage(file ="fondo.png")
    x = Label (image = bg_image)
    x.place(x=-2,y=-2)
    ventana.mainloop()
```

la problemática es que el traparente le quita TODO el color y solo quiero que se ponga el color del fondo
PD:si me sobran imports es que los saqué directamente del programa y no quiero error por falta de uno de ellos

Answer (score 0):

Antes que todo a qué se refiere con color de fondo no sólido, por lo cual eso que tiene que ver con el contexto de la pregunta, por lo que entiendo usted está tratando de asignar transparencia a widgets como labels y a la vez poner el color de fondo de los mismos, algo que no es posible.

En Tkinter, usted **puede** cambiar el nivel de transparencia de la ventana en general
por lo que hace que todos los widgets que estan presentes en la ventana sean transparentes, usted no puede aplicar transparencia a widgets específicos como labels o textos estáticos, botones, entre otros y mucho menos aplicar un color de fondo y transparencia a la vez.